# Stuck on orange screen during/after installing 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, installation, screen

I was using 10.10, so I did not want to upgrade. I downloaded the `ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` and **burn** into a pen-drive. I tried to install twice and both times, I got stucked on this orange screen without windows.

Then I downloaded again on a Mac, the same `.iso`, checked the md5 and burn to a CD. But again, I got the same orange screen.

I have four partitions, one is for `Windows OS`, the `second a free space` to files that I use on both OS, the `third are Ubuntu and swap`. Grub is OK.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed the 32bit version but happened exactly like you. Start Ubuntu in Recovery mode from Grub, from there, start session in `low graphics mode` (I don't remember the name exactly) and installed the graphic drivers, that solved my problem for now. You can do this from a terminal, or from Recovery mode too, it may work to you.